# ConEmu console buffer height not disabling?

Tags: shell, console, mingw, command-line-interface, conemu

I am using git bash in conemu, but when I start it up it buffers like thousand empty lines. Is there a way to disable that?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhZyi.png If you see in the picture, the scrollbar indicates that it loaded thousands of empty lines.I go into size&pos in the settings and unchecked long console output but nothing happens. I also tried to change the size of long console output to like 20 and it keeps reverting back to 1000.

Also, does anyone know how to get rid of the `@desktop-SJUQIIO` thing in the console right after my name and shorten the `/c/users/dylan` to show as `~` or something shorter?

Sorry for asking so many questions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> but when I start it up it buffers like thousand empty lines.

You have two choices: accept "thousand empty lines" (what's the problem?) or forget about backscroll ability. I believe, you would more disappointed, if you would not be able to scroll **back** and see long command output.

> does anyone know how to get rid of the @desktop-SJUQIIO

Learn about `PS1`.

Comment: Ok the thousand empty lines aren't really that big of a deal, but its just when I scroll with my trackpad, it just bolts from one place to another because of the scroll speed in this program. Do you know if I can change the scroll speed in conemu?